# SSL certificate intermediate CA

Tags: ssl, openssl

So I have a private key and an SSL Certificate. Is there a way to find out which CA signed it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the CA that issued your certificate is in the Issuer Distinguished Name (DN).

You can see all of this with OpenSSL using:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in the-certificate.pem
```

The name of the certificate's Issuer DN should match the name of the CA cert Subject DN.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with most browsers. Make sure you've navigated to your site so that the certificate has made a handshake with your browser. With Firefox, go to Tools -> Options and on the dialogue that pops up, you'll see an icon for "Advanced." Click that, then you'll see another tab below for "Encryption." Click that tab as well.

Now you can see a button that says "View Certificates." Clicking that will bring up a dialogue window showing the certificates that your system recognizes. The "servers" tab is where you will find the certificate for your site, and it will show you which CA signed it.

Comment: I meant more in-depth, like how does the browser does it? Thanks!

Comment: How does the browser find out who signed it?

Your browser downloads the certificate, which has the public key of the web server. This certificate is signed with the private key of the certificate authority that issued it. Your browser has the public keys of major certificate authorities installed in it, so that it can identify that it was indeed signed by the CA claiming to have done so.

Comment: Ok, how about this: I don't have a browser. All I have is a private key and a cert. Can I still find out who the CA is?

Comment: Who doesn't have a browser?

And yes, provided you can make software that does exactly what the browser does. Firefox is open source, so dig in and see how!